# alter deploy Django project, don't have css style in Django admin

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

when I open /admin site, terminal report some problems in pictures, and admin site don't have CSS styles

1. use it to let nginx get static files

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

2. add static files to nginx.conf

```
location /static {
   alias /Users/greendan/PycharmProjects/myTravel/; #static files
   uwsgi_pass 
    unix:/Users/greendan/PycharmProjects/myTravel/script/uwsgi.sock;

         }
```

3. this is my Nginx  config

```
server {
         listen       8088;
         server_name  127.0.0.1;

         charset utf-8;

         #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

         location / {
            #root   /Users/greendan/PycharmProjects/myTravel/;
            #index  templates/bootStrap.html;
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/Users/greendan/PycharmProjects/myTravel/script/uwsgi.sock;
          }
         location /static {
            alias /Users/greendan/PycharmProjects/myTravel/;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/Users/greendan/PycharmProjects/myTravel/script/uwsgi.sock;

         }
          location /media{
           alias /Users/greendan/PycharmProjects/myTravel/;
          }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

          # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
         #
          error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
         location = /50x.html {
              root   html;
         }
}
```

4. this is my uwsgi.ini

```
# use uwsig ini start
[uwsgi]
# project's file
chdir = /Users/greendan/PycharmProjects/myTravel
# project's application
module = myTravel.wsgi:application
# sock
socket = /Users/greendan/PycharmProjects/myTravel/script/uwsgi.sock
workers = 5
#pid 
pidfile = /Users/greendan/PycharmProjects/myTravel/script/uwsgi.pid
# ip and port 
http =127.0.0.1:8000
```

5. error report
   [picture Url](https://cdn.nlark.com/yuque/0/2019/png/220885/1558774413771-d693d8a8-7dd7-4ae5-be82-2ba22132193f.png)

Comment: this is [project tree](https://cdn.nlark.com/yuque/0/2019/png/220885/1558777309732-c6965d3e-d640-45b4-9b12-01e748b8b8c9.png), and this is  some code of my [urls.py](https://cdn.nlark.com/yuque/0/2019/png/220885/1558777926324-45d7b220-162f-4f16-8e57-0cd24e4eed99.png) and [settings.py](https://cdn.nlark.com/yuque/0/2019/png/220885/1558777955275-900a179b-3c33-436f-8230-58b6cfe27c71.png)

Answer (score 0):

it's not a big problem, just I don't know nginx' static file is not the same as the 
django's static file it's two different dir.

at the begin i make static_root and static_dir  is the same file, when search in jianshu and find a article to read more than twice, I know it's tow different dir,

and then, I make a static file in nginx and solve this problems quickly.

After this things, I find a big problems of myself, it's too careless, even I make this problems lots of times, but I still git it again